# How to go to extent programmatically?

Tags: openlayers-5

I am new to Openlayers 5 and I want to move the map to a specific extent programmatically.

I tried

```
var bbox = [485319.36436093575, 5749497.169086075, 498451.8156390643, 5758869.310913925];
map.getView().fit(bbox, {size: map.getSize()});
```

but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another method I should use? 
I didn't find anything in the API docs.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably in the question itself as a stackoverflow code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

It's working here.

```js
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View()
});

var bbox = [485319.36436093575, 5749497.169086075, 498451.8156390643, 5758869.310913925];
map.getView().fit(bbox, {size: map.getSize()});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Your example works for me, if I put the .fit-method directly after instantiation of the map. 
But I have a button with different bboxes. When I hit the button, the following code is run:

var bbox = [485319.36436093575, 5749497.169086075, 498451.8156390643, 5758869.310913925];
map.getView().fit(bbox, {size: map.getSize()});

And this does not work :(